# ElasticSearch query not returns exact match of an array

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, mongoosastic

I have a question regarding the query of an array of Elasticsearch. in my case, the structure of the custom attributes is an array of objects, each contains `inner_name` and `value`, the type of value are mixed (could be string, number, array, Date..etc), and one of the types is multi-checkbox, where it should take an array as an input. Mapping the `custom_attributes` as below:

```
"attributes" : {
              "properties" : {
                "_id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "inner_name" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "value" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
```

Where I used [mongoosastic](https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic) to indexing my MongoDB to ES, so the structure of the custom attributes was like:

```
[
  {
    customer_name: "customerX",
    "custom_attributes" : [
      {
        "group" : "xyz",
        "attributes" : [
          {
            "inner_name" : "attr1",
            "value" : 123,
          },       
          {
            "inner_name" : "attr2",
            "value" : [
              "Val1",
              "Val2",
              "Val3",
              "Val4"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    customer_name: "customerY",
    "custom_attributes" : [
      {
        "group" : "xyz",
        "attributes" : [
          {
          "inner_name" : "attr2",
            "value" : [
              "Val1",
              "Val2"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to perform a query where all values must be in the array. However, the problem with the below query is that it returns the document whenever it contains any of the values in the array. Here's the query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.inner_name": "attr2"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": [
              "val1",
              "val2",
              "val3",
              "val4"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For example, it returns both documents, where it should return just the first one only! what is wrong with my query? Is there another way to write the query?

Comment: Anybody can help?!

Answer (score 1):

The elasticsearch terms query tries to match any if any of your values is present in a document, think of the operator being `OR` instead of `AND` which is the one you want. There are two solutions for this

1. Use multiple `term` queries inside your bool must query, which will provide the needed `AND` functionality

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.inner_name": "attr2"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": "val1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": "val2"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": "val3"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": "val4"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Use the match query with the operator `AND` and `whitespace` analyzer. This **WILL NOT** work if your terms contain a whitespace

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.inner_name": "attr2"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "custom_attributes.attributes.value": {
              "query": "val1 val2 val3 val4",
              "operator": "and",
              "analyzer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I tried both ways but neither worked for me. I had to add `.keyword` after the value path to get the results, but the result was as I'm applying `OR` not `AND` operator. I didn't find another way to solve this, do you have any other ideas may help me? thanks in advance.